# Centos 7 Apache doesn't load .php file?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, php

Am using CentOS 7 Latest Version.

I already enabled httpd service and it's working file.

i did installed php and my issue started once i add php file to /var/www/html/

for example : test.php

now once i open server ip x.x.x.x/test.php ... i do see blank page?

what shall i do in that case??

php already installed !

httpd working fine but doesn't load php files !

Comment: Well, it is a good thing that you see a blank page.  If the page was not working you would get some HTTP error.  Seriously, you did not ever tell us what you mean by "i open server" (you mean you go into the server room and open the cover?)

Comment: Have you install `mod_php`?

Comment: Look at apache error log.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it seems to be abandoned by the asker, and is over a year old, so is likely obsolete to the asker.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit oddly phrased but as far as I can tell... you did not make the home page file an index.php file if you don't already have a file named that in the folder no file will load.

Comment: well, i created index.php file with code of <?php
phpinfo();
?>  under /var/www/html/ but it's keep showing blank page once loaded !

Comment: First make sure the ip address is the correct address and secondly, if that does not work, try reinstalling the Apache server because the steps may have been messed up in the process and make sure you get the steps from  a reliable source as many are often outdated.

Answer (score 0):

in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf I added:

LoadModule php5_module "/usr/lib64/php"

AddType application/x-httpd-php  .php

and found: DirectoryIndex index.html then add index.php

I also uncommitted include_path='.:/php/includes' in /etc/php.ini

Then, yum install php php-pear

Also changed ServerName in conf to localhost:80 and it works!

Now php working fine with httpd